# Read Shared Memory struct created in c++ by c#

Tags: c#, struct, mfc

I created shared memory in MFC application and im using the same shared memory in c#.So i want to use same structure used in c++.
But when i declared structure in c#,it shows array size can not be specfied in varaible declaration.
 But i want to know the size of structure while opening the shared memeory.

In  c++application:

```
struct TagModalDB
{

float    IV        [600];                   //Mapped to SIMPACK  VAR_I
char     FAIL      [600];                   //Mapped to SIMPACK  MALF_I
char     FD        [600];                   //Mapped to SIMPACK  REM_I
float    NCP       [600];
float    NLH       [600];
float    NENTH     [600];
float    NKVAL     [30][600];
float    NLEVEL    [600];
.....
};   //Its very lengthy structure

CreateFileMapping( (HANDLE) 0xFFFFFFFF, (LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES) NULL, PAGE_READWRITE,  0, sizeof( struct TagModalDB ),"ModelDB" );
```

in C# applicaiton:

```
    struct TagModalDB
    {

    float    IV        [600];                   
    char     FAIL      [600];                   
    char     FD        [600];                   
    float    NCP       [600];
    float    NLH       [600];
    };

     mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateOrOpen("ModelDB", Sizeof(TagModelDB) );
 accessor = mmf.CreateViewAccessor(0, Sizeof(TagModelDB), MemoryMappedFileAccess.Read);
```

How can i declare struct in c#. Im new to c#.
C++ application developed in vs2008. For c# application im using vs2010.

Comment: C++ structures are very different from C# structures. One thing to understand about C++ is packing, as in #pragma packing. You probably need to access the C++ structure as a byte array and copy each array (such as IV) to a corresponding C# array.

Answer (score 0):

This is how `C#` Structs are defined

> It is an error to define a default (parameterless) constructor for a
>   struct. It is also an error to initialize an instance field in a
>   struct body. **You can initialize struct members only by using a
>   parameterized constructor or by accessing the members individually
>   after the struct is declared**. Any private or otherwise inaccessible
>   members can be initialized only in a constructor.

You may use a code something like follow,

```
using System;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // make the instance
        TagModalDB test= new TagModalDB();

        // initialize the arrays
        test.intialize();

        Console.WriteLine(test.IV[599]); // <= Will out 0 since default assignment of 0  to numberic types
    }
}

// Your Struct 
public struct TagModalDB
{
    public float[]  IV;                   
    public char[]   FAI;                   
    public char[]   FD;                   
    public float[]  NCP;
    public float[]  NLH;


    // Here we initialize your arrays 
    public void intialize(){
        IV=new float[600] ;
        FAI= new char[600];
        FD= new char[600];
        NCP=new float[600];
        NLH= new float[600];
    }
}
```

Comment: the size of the struct returns as 24 . int size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(TagModalDB));  when im initializing the struct varialbes using Intialize() as you mentioned and also i didnt get values. But when declare the struct as unsafe and i used public fixed declaration. It returns correct size 12000 and also im getting values.

Comment: @Anu arrays are reference types in C#. A struct with arrays doesn't contain the array elements - only references to the elements.